# Override joomla category list view

Tags: php, view, joomla, overriding

I'm trying to change category title in joomla category list (list of all articles in a certain category) but I simply can't find the right file to override.

Files are supposed to be in `components\com_content\views\category\tmpl` and there's `default.php` that renders wrapper with a class of `.category-list` and `default_articles` which is rendering table with list of article names in a selected category.

What I can't find is file which renders category title and description. Here's the content of `default.php` as it might be the key. I don't quite understand what files it's calling since I haven't been in joomla development for ages.

```
<div class="category-list<?php echo $this->pageclass_sfx;?>">

<?php
$this->subtemplatename = 'articles';
echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.category_default', $this);
?>

</div>
```

This would be simple schematic of final render:

```
<div class="category-list">
...
[part I can't find]
<h2>Category title</h2>
<div class="category-desc">...</div>
[/part I can't find]
default_articles.php >> renders table with all articles in category
...
</div>
```

I have managed to override all other views without any problems but this one is very elusive.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Look in the layouts/content folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is located here:

```
/layouts/joomla/content/category_default.php
```

To override it place a copy here:

```
[YOUR_TEMPLATE]/html/layouts/joomla/content/
```

You can read more about Joomla layouts here:
[Sharing layouts across views or extensions with JLayout](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.3%3aSharing_layouts_across_views_or_extensions_with_JLayout)

Comment: I nearly cried from happiness after this worked. Thank you sir.

Comment: thank you!, why isn't this file in component i dont understand the joomla creator so confusing, they should list where the file is in the admin

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at layout overrides in joomla

http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla